# How many four digit numbers begin with $10$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many combinations are there for a four digit combination that starts with ten. I have a safe that requires four numbers and I know that the first two numbers are one and zero.  I do not remember the last two numbers.

Comment: Hint: How many combinations of **two** digits (0-9) are there?

Comment: I edited the title. See the advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Answer (score 4):

If you can use each of the numbers $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$ in each position, there are $10$ choices for the third number, and $10$ choices for the fourth number. As they are independent (choosing one does not restrict the choices of the other), there are $10\times 10 = 100$ different possibilities for the last two digits of the four digit code.

Answer (score 3):

$$\underline 1\quad \underline 0\quad \underline x\quad  \underline x$$

There is only one choice, already posted here, of each of the first two digits, namely, that they are $1, 0$ and in that order

How many options for the first digit $x, \; x \in\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}\,? $

- You're right, there are 10 digits, each of which can be placed in the third slot.

For each digit chosen for the first digit, how many options for the second digit $x\,?$

- Again, for each choice of digit placed in the third slot, there are
  10 digits, each of which can be placed in the last slot.

That gives us $$1\times 1\times 10 \times 10 = 10^2 = 100$$ possible 4-digit combinations to choose from, given that the combinations must begin with a one immediately followed by a zero.

Answer (score 1):

The number of permutations is the same as the number for $2$ consecutive digits (because you've only got 2 positions left). There are $10$ digits to choose for each of $2$ positions so $x=10^2=100$.